# Regex and Create Separate File with before and after count text

Tags: luatex, luacode

When I have running `LuaLaTeX filename.tex` all the PI Instructions tags only like `<?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?>` and `<?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?>` should be store to separate filename called `LuaLaTeXpi.tex`.

It should be get before and after text like `their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical propert`. The counts of the before and after should be minimum 25 characters.

So, the expected the `LuaLaTeXPi.TeX` file like below:

```
their environment change Sample XXX1 their mechanical propert

rrying mechanical loads, \hspace*{12pt}Abc alleviate vibration, red

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction", function(el)
  return el:get_attribute("text")
end)
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can get  the surrounding text and save it to an extra file using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>]]

-- open LuaLaTeXpi file
local apifile = io.open("LuaLaTeXpi.tex", "w")

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
  

local function save_pi(el)
  -- get preceding and following element
  local before = el:get_sibling_node(-1)
  local after = el:get_sibling_node(1)
  local before_text, after_text = "", ""
  -- get surrounding 25 characters
  if before then 
    before_text = before:get_text()
    before_text = before_text:sub(-25)
  end
  if after then
    after_text = after:get_text()
    after_text = after_text:sub(1,25)
  end
  local text = before_text ..  el._attr[ "_text" ] ..  after_text .. "\n"
  apifile:write(text)
end
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      save_pi(child)
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

-- don't forget to close the file
apifile:close()

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par", {verbatim=true})
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction", function(el)
  return el:get_attribute("text")
end)
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

This is the contents of `LuaLaTeXpi.tex`:

```
their environment change  Sample XXX1 their mechanical propert
rrying mechanical loads,  \hspace*{12pt}Abc alleviate vibration, red
```

---

Original answer:

I don't completely understand the question, so I will answer in two ways:

1. To print the transformed XML code in your PDF result, your code mostly works correctly. However, there is a problem with LaTeX math in your XML snippet, which will appear as raw LaTeX code instead of formatted math. In the latest version of LuaXML, you can use the `{verbatim=true}` property to prevent characters from being escaped:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par", {verbatim=true})
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction", function(el)
  return el:get_attribute("text")
end)
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. The second interpretation of your question is that you want to write the output to a separate file. In that case, you wouldn't use a TeX document, but just a Lua script. You can redirect its output to a file using shell pipes.

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par", {verbatim=true})
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction", function(el)
  return el:get_attribute("text")
end)
print(transformer:process_dom(dom))
```

The only change from the code in the first variant is the use of `kpse.set_program_name "luatex"`, which is necessary if you want to load LuaTeX libraries, and `print(transformer:process_dom(dom))`, because we want to print the transformed document to the terminal output.

You can execute it using:

```
$ texlua myscript.lua > LuaLaTeXPi.TeX
```

This is the resulting TeX file:

```
\section{Scattering of flexural waves an electric current}
Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic 
noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or
reacting to their environment change  Sample XXX1 their mechanical
properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying 
mechanical loads,  \hspace*{12pt}Abc alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic 
noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor 
their own condition.\par
```

Comment: Thanks for your information about `verbatim` and I have modified the question and what i have required. The file should store with `before PI after` text. The counts before and after minimum 25 characters.

Comment: @Balaji so you don't actually want to translate the whole document, but produce just some snippets around PI instructions instead?

Comment: No, I have need to process whole `LaTeX` file and need to get `PDF` output with get the PI tags in separate file.

Comment: @Balaji I hope that it is correct now

Comment: Excellent Work what i have expected. Thanks. What is the meaning of `ntype == "PI"` and `_attr[ "_text" ]`.

Comment: @Balaji `ntype` comes from `child:get_node_type()`, and it tests current node type. it can be element, text, processing instruction, or some other types. So we execute the condition only for processing instructions. `child._attr[ "_text" ]` contains text of that processing instruction.

Comment: It should be work include element also like `<LuaLaTeX> Sample XXX1 </LuaLaTeX>`. I have tried and not working. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Balaji that would be more difficult if you want to limit the surrounding text to 25 characters, because you could cut commands in the middle with that condition. For plain text it doesn't matter.