# Read the text from One File and Replace with Another LaTeX file using RegEX

Tags: luatex, luacode

Using [Regex and Create Separate File with before and after count text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673385/regex-and-create-separate-file-with-before-and-after-count-text) this, I have exported PI Instructions from Original `LaTeX` file and stored in a separate LaTeX file `Global_PItexts.tex`.

Now, I would like to read PI instructions from `Global_PItexts.tex` file and insert PI instructions in the Original LaTeX file back.

My Original LaTeX file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment \textit{change} xxxxxxxxx Sample XXX1 their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, Abc alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>]]

-- open LuaLaTeXpi file
local apifile = io.open("Global_PItexts.tex", "rb")

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)

--Get Before and After Text
local function check_pi(el)
  local before = el:get_sibling_node(-1)
  local after = el:get_sibling_node(1)
  local before_text, after_text = "", ""
  -- get surrounding 50 characters
  if before then 
    before_text = before:get_text()
    before_text = before_text:sub(-50)
  end
  if after then
    after_text = after:get_text()
    after_text = after_text:sub(1,50)
  end
  local text = before_text .. "<!" .. el._attr[ "_text" ] .. "!>" .. after_text .. "\n"
  apifile:read(text)
  --- How to print apifile text here in terminal/command?
  print ("TEXT IS",apifile)
end
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

My `Global_PItexts.tex` is:

```
or reacting to their environment \textit{change} <!--LuaLaTeX xxxxxxxxx Sample XXX1--> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and

manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <!--LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc--> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, chang

mechanical properties as required or monitor their <!--\linebreak --> own condition.
```

Expected output LaTeX file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment \textit{change} <?LuaLaTeX xxxxxxxxx Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their <?LuaLaTeX \break?> own condition.</para>
</art>]]
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Read the `Global_PItexts.tex` file and insert the PI instruction with Original `LaTeX` file. How to achieve this?

Comment: @michal: Any ideas above my requirements?

Comment: @michal: I have waiting for your ideas any....